# Can I change the message on FB.Connect.logout?

Tags: facebook, message, logout

I use FB.Connect.logout to log out from Facebook but every time the pop up says:

> "You are logging out of both this site and Facebook"

Is there any way I can change this message?

Answer (score 1):

No. You must provide a chance to log out from both sides. It's in their Terms of service